# How XML DOM Object is being loaded in Memory from Disk

Tags: c++, xml, dom

Hello and happy new year.
I need a little guide through process of loading a XML DOM from disk to memory with C++, on windows.

Microsoft provide this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765465(v=vs.85).aspx), but it doesn't cover the actual process of what ntKernel Functions are being used to do this, and it doesn't explain what process is behind the actual load .

Does the main process make a call to kernel function to load xml from disk to mem?

```
   VariantFromString(L"stocks.xml", varFileName);
   pXMLDom->load(varFileName, &varStatus);
```

Or there is global process that handle request's to load, and then after it load xml via Kernel Functions, it make's a link to DOM Object, and return it to the process were it was asking.

I want to know what Kernel Function does the job for loading .xml file from disk ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is no kernel function for 'loading XML' (at least not one used by the DOMDocument60 coclass.

Instead it simply uses generic file reading calls (in the kernel this is ZwReadFile), the DOMDocument60 code then parses the file content into whatever internal representation it uses.

The only context switch involved will be between user and kernel mode not between one process, kernel mode and another process (unless perhaps some kind of user-mode file system is involved but if it were you likely wouldn't need to be asking this question).